# Как запрограммировать кнопку Add для файловых полей?

Tags: javascript

В форме регистрации нужна кнопка, которая создает файловое поле. К примеру, жмем на кнопку Add - создается файловое поле fupload1, жмем еще раз - создается fupload2, жмем еще разок - появляется fupload3 и так далее до fupload20, не больше. Мне говорили, что скрипт простой, но я js не знаю. (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery решение:

```
<button name="add">Add</button>
<div id="placer"></div>

<script>
  var i=0;
  if (i<20){
     $("button[name=add]").click(function(i){
         i++;
        $("#placer").append("<input name='fupload"+i+"' value='' type='file'/>");
         return false;
     });
</script><br/>
```

Плюс подключить библиотеку jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, простой. Проверку на количество я опустил - ее легко дописать самому.

```
<script>
function dupl(x){
    x = x.parentNode;
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(x.cloneNode(true), x);
}
</script>
<div><input type="file" name="fupload[]" /><span onclick="dupl(this)">+</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id = "fupload">
</div>
<input type = "button" value = "AddField" onclick="
  (function(button){
    var curr = 0,
        max = 20,
        name = 'fupload',
        container = 'fupload';

    container = document.getElementById( container );

    var fn = function(){
      if ( curr <= max ){
        curr++;
        container.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );
        var field = document.createElement('input');
        field.name = name + curr;
        field.type = 'file';
        container.appendChild( field );
      };
    };

    fn();

    button.onclick = fn;
  })(this);
">
```

Comment: Какой ужас - засовывать такой код в onclick!!

Comment: Где ужас-то?) Что его мешает вытащить? 
А вот человеку, который не знает тега <script> - такой рецепт удобнее, имхо.